# zsh: command not found: --name; docker: invalid reference format Docker

Tags: docker

First, I had created the network:

```
docker network create pg-network
```

Then I tried to use this code of lines for Docker but it has not worked:

```
docker run -it \
  -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \
  -v /Users/ruslanpilipyuk/Desktop/data-engineering-zoomcamp-main/week_1_basics_n_setup/2_docker_sql/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  -p 5431:5432 \
  --network=pg-network \ 
  --name pg-database \
  postgres:13
```

As result, I got this:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
zsh: command not found: --name
```

Comment: As you've copied the command into the question, there is a space after the backslash at the end of the `--network` line.  Is that there in your actual command?  It could cause pretty much exactly this error.

Answer (score 0):

very simple, you can try backspace **postgres:13** up to above line.

```
docker run -it \ 
 -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \
 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \
 -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \
 -v /Users/ruslanpilipyuk/Desktop/data-engineering-zoomcamp-main/week_1_basics_n_setup/2_docker_sql/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
 -p 5431:5432 \
 --network=pg-network \ 
 --name pg-database postgres:13
```